# Bayes by backprop unbiased monte carlo gradients

Tags: bayesian, bayesian-network, variational-bayes

I am currently trying to understand a paper on [bayesian neural networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.05424) whereby the authors use a *bayes by backprop* approach to learn weight uncertainties in the neural networks.

I am trying to understand the derivation for **proposition 1** in the paper. Particularly, I am not sure how

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\int f(\boldsymbol{w},\theta)q(\epsilon)d\epsilon = E_{q(\epsilon)}[\frac{\partial f(w,\theta)}{\partial w} \frac{\partial w}{\partial \theta} + \frac{\partial f(w,\theta)}{\partial \theta}]$$

I am not sure why there is an additional $\frac{\partial f(w,\theta)}{\partial \theta}$ inside the expectation ? since I thought $\frac{\partial f(w,\theta)}{\partial w} \frac{\partial w}{\partial \theta} = \frac{\partial f(w,\theta)}{\partial w}$

Comment: isn't the first term inside the expectation quantity on the left hand side equal to the right hand side term by chain rule?

Answer (score 3):

Okay I think this is why there is an additional term. $f$ is a function of $\textbf{w}$ and $\theta$. Since $\textbf{w}$ is composed of $\theta$, we apply chain rule to obtain $\frac{\partial f}{\partial w}\frac{\partial w}{\partial \theta}$. Since $f$ is also a function of $\theta$. we also differentiate with respect to $\theta$, yielding $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}$

Comment: yes (+1), it's the [*multivariable* chain rule](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calciii/chainrule.aspx). And the reason why you can swap the order of integration and differentiation is the proposition on slide 7 [here](https://github.com/tbrown122387/stat7200_slides/blob/master/slide17.pdf)